# JQuery, CSS - create rating system

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have following code.
HTML:

```
<div class="zuta_strana_ocena">
<p>Vaša ocena</p>
<div class="zuta_strana_rating">
<span role="rating" id="star_1"></span>
<span role="rating" id="star_2"></span>
<span role="rating" id="star_3"></span>
<span role="rating" id="star_4"></span>
<span role="rating" id="star_5"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.zuta_strana_ocena {float: left; width: 65%; margin-top: 10px}
.zuta_strana_ocena p {float: left}
.zuta_strana_rating {height: 30px; width: 180px; display: block; float: left;}
span[role=rating] {display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px; float: left; margin-right: 5px;background: url(../img/resursi/rating.png) 0 0 no-repeat; cursor: pointer}
span[role=rating]:first-of-type {margin-left: 5px}
.star, .on {background: url(../img/resursi/rating.png) 0 -49px no-repeat !important; }
```

JQuery:

```
ocena.hover(
function(){
$(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('star')},
function(){
$(this).parent().children().removeClass('star');
}
); 

ocena.on('click', function(){
d_o = $(this).index() + 1;
$(this).parent().children().removeClass('on');
$(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('on')          
});
```

At the moment it is working fine if I want to create all start with same picture, but that is what I don't need. Every star have to have unique image, but at the moment I don't know the solution. I tried this CSS:

```
#star_1 .star, #star_1 .on {background: url(../img/resursi/rating.png) 0 -49px no-repeat !important; }
```

but it is not working (nothing is happening). What I need to do to make it work?

JSFiddle link:
[http://jsfiddle.net/j5vce/](http://jsfiddle.net/j5vce/1/)

Comment: can you post a demo at jsfiddle.net

Comment: Link: http://jsfiddle.net/j5vce/1/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/j5vce/7/

Try this
i just gave them classes each of the tiles
and added a background to them

*edited
(you can even just point to the ID of them)
*edited 1.

The link now shows 1 current state and then 
3 unique states

Comment: btw 
first-of-type that you use is a css 3 selector so rememeber it wont work in IE8 and less

You could use as a jquery selector instead
tr:nth-last-child(1)
remember this goes from 1 and up and not like index which you might know is 0 1 2

Comment: I need it to place unique image (color) on hover, and one image as default state (current setting).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j5vce/7/
the 3 first have the unique and the last 2 have the default state

Answer (score 1):

You may try suggestion by Simon Pertersen. But better use an Image Sprite like the one below;

[image]

You may assign this to your `span`'s parent selector and may change image position. In this method, the stars will load fast since the image is already preloaded.